# arcpy command for "Select by location" tool?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, esri, arcpy

I have the following data :

- a raster catalog
- a feature class composed of several polygons.

The polygons and the raster catalog often overlap.
I want to get the polygons (the ENTIRE polygon, not part of it, and not a clip or an intersect...) which contain the raster catalog or part of it, so that I can run processes on those areas.

I checked some tools in ArcMap, and I observed that the "**Select by location**" tool works perfectly (and NOT the tool Select Layer by location). The result is a selection of only the polygons (from the feature class layer) that contain the raster catalog. But I can't find anything about an arcpy command...

I found the "**SelectLayerByLocation_management**" (Select Layer by location tool) but the resulting selection is empty, so it doesn't do the job. Plus I cannot use a ratser catalog as selecting feature, so it's a no.

Does anyone have information regarding the "**Select by location**" tool adptation to arcpy ?
I have to use a tool that can handle raster catalog.

Comment: SelectLayerByLocation_management is the ArcPy equivalent of "Select by Location" in ArcMap. SelectLayerByLocation_management does support Raster Catalog Layer as the in_layer. If you post the code that you tried then we can give you feedback on what you may have done wrong.

Comment: I think there are many more potential answerers of ArcPy questions at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange but they will expect to see a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided not to use the raster catalog, but the map index provided with the images used to create the catalog.

I then used the arcpy command "Select Layer by Location", which does not work with raster catalogs, but works fine with map index.